# Ruby 1.9+ style hash syntax doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3

I'm running ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0] on my macbook.

Yet, when I attempt to use "new style" hashes such as:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
```

I get an error that reads `"unexpected: expecting )"`

I can fix this issue by replacing with the "old style" hashrockets:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
```

I'm trying to figure out why rails isn't allowing the new style of ruby hashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no Rails 1.9.3. Without seeing what you're actually doing, reasonably-formatted, it's tough to say, since obviously the new hash syntax works--did you try adding the parens, and/or explicitly using `{}`?

Comment: (And obviously sanity-checking that you're running Rails under the Ruby you believe you are.)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like rails is running under system ruby while you have RVM installed as 1.9.3 (I would guess)

Try

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

Then reset your console and do

```
$ ruby -v
```

to double check

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the quick assistance. I typo'd in the original post. I meant to say "Rails 3.2.3" in that last sentence. I've tried to issue the command above, but I think something is wrong with my path. I get "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login." This is something I've been researching online but unable to find the answer. I can't find a terminal setting that allows me to specify whether it's a shell login.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your .bash_profile (or bashrc or whatever you are using):

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

After that, of course, issue the source command then:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm info
```

Which should work and display all the information about the current ruby version and gemset. The new hash syntax failing because you are not actually running ruby 1.9.3. Doing "ruby -v" should confirm the problem.  Given your comment above, you rvm **has** to be a function in order for it to work.

Also, What operating system are you running?